# Android: Displaying data in a list view at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-listview

In my android application user can create an account and username and his profile picture will save in the sqlite database. Profile picture is saved with its' uri. Now I want to retrieve those data (username and profile picture) from the database and list them in a list view when the app is loading. I've already implemented retrieving data part. It works fine. And also I've already loaded them in a table layout. But actually it's not what I want. I need to display those data in a list view. Can anyone plz be so kind enough to explain how can I achieve this.

Comment: post something what you've done yet

Comment: Refer @ http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you can load your data to a table layout, you've already finished 50% of the work. You should write your own custom adapter to fetch data from data structure you used (like arraylist), and xml for custom row item.

I've already answered a detailed example here [Populate list of custom view using ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16291459/1589566)