# how to set values from an array into a listview using custom adapter and give different colors to row

Tags: android

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Cola", "Dove", "Elephant", "Fan", "Grapes", "Horse" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>((this, R.layout.row,R.id.textview1, values);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(the class which contains the above code extends ListActivity)
I want to give different background colors to different row(For example: The background color of the
textview1 should be green at position 0, red at position 6, blue at position 7) For this it is said 
that I need to use custom adapter, but I don't know how to set these particular values 
Apple,Banana,Cola,...etc to the textview1 using a custom adapter. My xml file row.xml is as shown below

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/ListItem"
    android:background="@color/color3"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color1" />
```

I don't know how to implement a customadapter. Can anyone help me to set these values to
the `TextView` by using a custom adapter and set different background colors to the `TextView`?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16292942/1589566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give your TextView in row.xml an id (Let's say rowText)

You need to create an Adapter which will bind itself to your ListView. The adapter can in general look like this:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] values = new String[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Cola", "Dove", "Elephant", "Fan", "Grapes", "Horse" };

public ThumbnailAdapter(MainActivity m) {
    thumbnails = thumbs;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(m);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return values[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rowText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rowText);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
            //Set the text here!
            holder.rowText.setText(values[position]);
            //Set the color here!
            holder.rowText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView rowText;
}
}
```

This is just a start for you. To change the colours you can set an array of colours and select from the position as well. Hope it helps! (I have not tested the code but it should be mostly correct)