# Fragment Class with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Is it possible to have custom `ListView` inside `Fragment` class?

This is my fragment class wherein the `fragment_find_people` is just an empty `XML`:

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Now, I've already have a `customListView` but it only works with the `Activity` class. How can I transfer that to `Fragment`?

my listview_main xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/listmain" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:divider="#9c9c9c"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291459/populate-list-of-custom-view-using-listfragment

Comment: @EugenMartynov I'am using Fragment Class not Activity Class

Comment: @user3138250 Post some more code. What have you tried for this ?

Comment: @user3138250 Have you tried to bind the listview with some data?

Comment: i tried in Activity class but not yet in Fragment Class

Comment: By the way, you should no more use fill_parent for width and height in android xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class context replace with `getActivity` thats only difference and replace view not activity:

```java
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
//now you must initialize your list view
Listview listview =(Listview)rootView .findViewById(R.id.your_listview);

//EDITED Code 
String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 

listview.setAdapter(adapter);  

//To have custom list view use this : you must define CustomeAdapter class
//listview.setadapter(new CustomeAdapter(getActivity()));
//getActivty is used instead of Context
return view;
```

Comment: this is my main class if iam using Activity class [link](http://pastie.org/8586865)
now i want to transfer this codes wherein my main class is a fragment

Comment: http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2013/07/full-example-of-using-fragment-in.html this link 100 % solve your issue

Comment: Sir it is not working the tutorial is very confusing. do you have a sample of it?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the onCreateView method first define your layout.

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.status,container, false);
        list=(ListView) rl.findViewById(R.id.list1);
         itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

          // fill the defined arraylist using and asynctask or any other method

           adapter=new Customadapt(context.getActivity(), itemList);        
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           return rl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes, it is possible. Here is how.

As with all other resources, there are two ways to declare them. Programatically and via XML layout files. I'll explain using XML as it is what I use most often and I find best.

In your `fragment_find_people` `XML`, declare your layout as normal. In that layout, I presume at least a `LinearLayout`, you need to add a `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_find_people_linear_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
        android:id="@id/your_list_view_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can just instantiate that `ListView` using:

```
Listview listView =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
```

In order to use the "same" `ListView`, I would recommend simply duplicating the code of the `ListView` from one layout file, the one for your `Activity` to the `Fragment`. You could also separate the declaration of the `ListView` into a separate XML, which would be tidier if you'd be to reuse it a lot, but for a small project, just copy it.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. The class is called `ListView` (note the CamelCase) not `Listview`. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom list view programmatically also. for ex:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return new CustomListView(container.getContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreateView(...) method, call your CustomListAdapter like this

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity());
customListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And your CustomListAdapter as follows , e.g

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

    }

 .......
 .......
}
```