# I am getting error when i use Fragment,Tabspager in Android java file

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-gridview

I have created 3 fragment java files and used TabsPager file to swipe the fragments. Now I added working code on StoreHomeFragment.java code added to storehomefragment is collection of populating into gridview

but now I am get error in TabsPager

TabsPagerAdapterStore.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapterStore extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapterStore(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0: return new StoreGenreFragment();
    case 1: return new StoreHomeFragment(); //this line error 
    case 2: return new StoreStepFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}}
```

And in "case 1" above error is popped up. I use right click and Quick Fix

```
Change method return type to StoreHomeFragment
```

I have uploaded the image as well to just show the error popping up if I choose that one then every other fragments in the switch case will get error can please anyone help me what mistake I might have committed

> [image]

And the code which is present in StoreHomeFragment.java

```
public class StoreHomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_home, container, false);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    // Gridview
    final GridView gridView1 = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_home_gridview); 

    String url = "http://192.168.1.132/Android/App/good.php";

    try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
            map.put("artist", c.getString("artist"));
            map.put("price", c.getString("price"));
            map.put("image", c.getString("image"));


            MyArrList.add(map);
        }           

        //gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));
        gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;    
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code of StoreHomeFragment class

Comment: at case one try casting it to a Fragment,if it is extending a fragment class like, case 1: return (Fragment) new StoreHomefragment();

Comment: @insomniac ya i will try it and let you know

Comment: @insomniac same error yaar i am not able to understand what is happening if i type cast it also it is not working

Comment: @Kedarnath pls help me yaar

Comment: Please paste the code of StoreHomeFragment class

Comment: @Kedarnath i will edit here only ha

Comment: @Kedarnath pls check the StoreHomeFragment.java code

Comment: @Kedarnath Can u pls help me in correcting the error

Comment: @SandeepV please paste the code of `StoreGenreFragment` class as well.

Comment: @Kedarnath no i have not added anything there yaar only i added to StoreHomeFragment class but it happened like this

Comment: I know, but I want to see its code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52179/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-sandeep-v)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `StoreHomeFragment` extends `Fragment` and, if you use the support library, check your class imports because `Fragment` class is also contained in support library. Pratically you have to import the same `Fragment` class that you use in `StoreGenreFragment` or `StoreStepFragment`

Comment: check the above code i have already the extends fragment @ethe

Comment: Ya i have added in my project but i havent pasted it because the people who answer question must understand correctly where i am getting issie so @ethe