# ListFragment cause error when inserting listactivity in Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am working on Navigaion Drawer and I have inserted ListActivity in Fragment Activity and change Fragment to ListFragment. But still i am getting error . Please kindly see th logcat and let me know what whould i do to rectify the error.

I want to see the ListActivity in Fragment.

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends ListFragment {
        public boolean net;
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvItemName;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
     ListView listview;

    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twit_list, container,
                false);


        downloadTweets();


          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {   
                 // selected item
                 String lst_txt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();

                 System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt ); 
                 // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                 Intent i = new Intent(FragmentOne.this.getActivity(), SingleListItem.class);
                 // sending data to new activity
                 i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
                 startActivity(i);
               }
            });







        return view;

    }


    public void downloadTweets() {
        TwitterUser o = new TwitterUser();
        String m = o.getValue();

         System.out.println("Kida   "+m);
          listview = this.getListView();
          String ScreenName =m;

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }



    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
        private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "kJ9cZesXIjdztc6fubuhygvkqU";
            final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "njinbjinjimjimionuiXGonaIcWTG";
            final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
            final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";


            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
            @Override
            // can use UI thread here
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                try{
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FragmentOne.this.getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loader_2));
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ! Unwrapping Something for You...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
                String result = null;

                if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                    result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
                }
                return result;
            }

            // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

                // lets write the results to the console as well
                for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
                }

              /// ArrayAdapter<Tweet> al = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>();
                //  listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));

                System.out.println("Kamina "+ twits);

                // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
            //  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
            //  setListAdapter(adapter);


                    ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.customgrid,R.id.texts, twits);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);



        //      ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,twits); 

             //   setListAdapter(myAdapter);

            //    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.customgrid,arr);
             //   lst.setAdapter(ad);

                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
            private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
                Twitter twits = null;
                if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                        // just eat the exception
                    }
                }
                return twits;
            }

            // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
            private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
                Authenticated auth = null;
                if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                        // just eat the exception
                    }
                }
                return auth;
            }

            private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                    if (statusCode == 200) {

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } else {
                        sb.append(reason);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
                } catch (IOException ex2) {
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
                String results = null;

                // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
                try {
                    // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                    String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                    String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                    // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                    // encoded consumer secret
                    String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                    // Base64 encode the string
                    String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                    // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                    String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                    Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                    // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                    // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                    if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                        // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName+"&count=10");

                        // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                        // header with the value of Bearer <>
                        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        // update the results with the body of the response
                        results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
                }
                return results;
            }
        }


}
```

logcat

```
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:280)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.iamrajkaran.navigation.FragmentOne.downloadTweets(FragmentOne.java:112)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.iamrajkaran.navigation.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:77)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-17 07:04:10.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think   `listview = this.getListView();` cause an Error.

Comment: @MD no its not it is still giving  run time error
NullPointerException

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291459/populate-list-of-custom-view-using-listfragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291459/populate-list-of-custom-view-using-listfragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not initialized correctly your `ListView` object.

Try the following:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twit_list, container,
            false);
listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.list); //This is probably the id for your listview if you have defined it correctly
```

And then remove `listview = this.getListView();` from your `downloadTweets()` method.

Another possibility could be to move your `downloadTweets()` and your `setOnClickListener` to a method that will be called afterwards, such as `onStart`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling UI related methods like `getListView(`) but the view is not ready yet. You should use the method `onViewCreated()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.twit_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public View onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    downloadTweets();
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for considering question , but it is solved by other factor.