# getView() doesn't get called in custom adapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am making a note taking app in Android. I want to display a ListView in a ListFragment in the main activity. But the list does not appear as the getView method is not getting called in the custom adapter. I read a lot of SO posts and tried many solutions but none of them seem to work for me. getCount() method works fine and returns the correct data size and not 0, but it is getting called around 3 to 4 times.

I have checked the values of getAllNotes(), getCount(), notesListView, notesList, adapter and they are all returning the correct values. I set breakpoints in my code and debugged it, but execution does not stop at breakpoints set in the getView() method so I know that's where the problem lies.

My list fragment (NotesListFragment.java):

```
package com.example.sriramkailasam.notes;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NotesListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println("notes list fragment attached");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
             LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("fragment going to inflate layout");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("fragment view created");
        NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(context,
                        R.layout.notes_list_item,
                        R.id.list_no_items,
                        getAllNotes());
        ListView notesListView = getListView();
        notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private ArrayList<Note> getAllNotes() {
        openAndQueryDatabase();
        return notesList;
    }

    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery =
                "SELECT title, body FROM " + DatabaseContract.NotesEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                Note note = new Note();
                note.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                note.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));

                notesList.add(note);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("cursor is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter (NotesAdapter.java):

```
package com.example.sriramkailasam.notes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class NotesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {
    private int resourceId;
    private List<Note> notes;

    public NotesAdapter(Context context,
                        int resource,
                        int textViewResourceId,
                        List<Note> notesList) {
        super(context, resource,textViewResourceId, notesList);
        resourceId = resource;
        notes = notesList;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("getCount called: " + notes.size());
        return notes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Note getItem(int position) {
        return notes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView called");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, true);
        }

        TextView titleTextView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        TextView bodyTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_body);
        titleTextView.setText((getItem(position)).getTitle());
        bodyTextView.setText((getItem(position)).getBody());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Row layout (notes_list_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout (fragment_notes_list.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sriramkailasam.notes.NotesListFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_no_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat output:

```
    06-19 15:35:45.466 14513-14524/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14374(578KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 6.269ms total 27.655ms
06-19 15:35:45.686 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes-1/lib/arm
06-19 15:35:45.700 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-19 15:35:45.792 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-19 15:35:46.001 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: notes list fragment attached
06-19 15:35:46.002 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: fragment going to inflate layout
06-19 15:35:46.008 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: fragment view created
06-19 15:35:46.018 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: getCount called: 30
06-19 15:35:46.018 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: getCount called: 30
06-19 15:35:46.018 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: getCount called: 30
06-19 15:35:46.018 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: getCount called: 30
06-19 15:35:46.018 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/System.out: getCount called: 30
06-19 15:35:46.086 14513-14550/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 48a5bf5, I15255e4b4a
                                                                          Build Date                       : 02/22/17
                                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                                          Local Branch                     : 
                                                                          Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.5.R1.07.00.00.269.019
                                                                          Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                          Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
06-19 15:35:46.092 14513-14550/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-19 15:35:46.092 14513-14550/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-19 15:35:46.125 14513-14513/com.example.sriramkailasam.notes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: You should use `Toast` instead of  `System.out.println("getView called");`

Comment: And also, this line `ListView notesListView = getListView();` looked wrong.

Comment: I don't want the user to see what method is getting called. The print statement is for me to debug the program.

Comment: I debugged it and notesListView returns the correct ListView. But I do not see getView getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialized your listView.

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list,
                    container, false);
            notesListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.yourListView);

            return rootView;
        }
```

Then

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("fragment view created");
        NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(context,
                        R.layout.notes_list_item,
                        R.id.list_no_items,
                        getAllNotes());
        notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Edit

```
 private ArrayList<Note> getAllNotes() {
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery =
            "SELECT title, body FROM " + DatabaseContract.NotesEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Note note = new Note();
            note.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            note.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));

            notesList.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("cursor is null");
    }
        return noteList;
}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but the ListView still does not appear.

Comment: What are `R.layout.notes_list_item,
                        R.id.list_no_items` ?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that. R.layout.notes_list_item is the custom row layout file that I have included. R.id.list_no_items is the id of the TextView that is supposed to be displayed when the list is empty.

Comment: Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291459/populate-list-of-custom-view-using-listfragment)

Comment: I was using the ViewHolder pattern that the answer suggests before I asked this question, and that did not work for me either.

Comment: How you know it is not getting called ? Does it shows code never used in IDE ?

Comment: Yes the print statement that I put in there does not appear in logcat. Also the execution does not stop at the breakpoints I set in the getView method when I debug it.

Comment: getAllNotes() was working well from the start and changing it made no difference.

Comment: I have checked values of all getAllNotes, notesList, notesListView, adapter, getCount and everything is working great but the only problem is that getView is not getting called so my ListView is not showing up. I even tried changing layout_height properties of elements in xml.

Comment: Remove @override

Comment: If you are talking about removing @Override from the getView(), it did not work, and I don't see why it should work anyway.